# Tomcat issue:The last packet successfully received from the server was 66,913,221 milliseconds ago.

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have installed tomcat on centos and deployed a java web application. I'm using mysql db. Everyday in the morning when I try to login as first user, it gieves me the following error:

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
>   Reason: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 66,913,221 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 66,913,221 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

After this, When I try to relogin, it allows me to do so.

I have include the following in my context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/CAR" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="30000"
           username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://130.1.18.2:3306/car" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow = true/>
```

Any help on this, I would appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to add **autoReconnect=true** parameter to the jdbc string to keep it alive when not receiving packets. In your case it would be

```
    jdbc:mysql://130.1.18.2:3306/car?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Ok just add it. I will test it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. The autoreconnect = true has not worked!

Answer (score 1):

or if you can, you can change to other database pool. I has the same problem before, and the autoReconnect not work for me. Now I am using HikariCP. this problem gone.

Comment: What is HikariCP? I'm using mysql as DB

Comment: Can i use it with tomcat?

Comment: you can. I use it with tomcat. But i use spring boot. as for you, https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.).  but the sample is oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
autoReconnect=true
```

is not working as per my knowledge, `Mysql` having its own connection closure timeout. `ORM` will mark it as `stale connection` if `Mysql` closes the connection.